# How to get average of the row with minimun and maximun excluded in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, mean

There are five colums.
How to get average of the row (not column) and
the average should be made with minimum and maximum excluded.

If there are duplicate maximum or(and) minimum, how to exlude them all?

The result of my data should be like this.

```
Average_MIN_MAX_excluded
-------------------------
3.33333333
5.33333333
```

My data set is as below;

```
WITH DATAA AS
(SELECT 3 c1,5 c2,4 c3,3 c4 ,1 c5 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT  1 c1,3 c2,6 c3,9 c4 ,7 c5 FROM DUAL)
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 FROM DATAA;
```

Comment: What if your max or min value are multiple times in your table. Like 1,3,4,5,1? What should be expected output then?

Comment: @Tejash thank you. If that happen, I want to exclude them all. 1,3,4,5,1 -> 3,4  and the oupt shoud be 3.5

Answer (score 2):

```
select ((c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5) -
          greatest( c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 ) -
          least( c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 ))/ 3
  from DATAA
```

would be one way.  Here's a [liveSQL link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/jdg8ck8jwzvcp0cvzjrj50gsz)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good place to use [`LATERAL JOIN`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1) aka `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT AVG(c) AS Average_MIN_MAX_excluded
 FROM (
  SELECT c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c) rn
  FROM (
    SELECT c1 c FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT c2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT c3 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT c4 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT c5 FROM dual) 
 )
 WHERE rn NOT IN (1,5)
) s;
```

This method allows to easily exclude 1,2,3 highest/lowest values if necessary.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4434f645af1c4423b17cf86dbd33973)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `unpivot` and `analytical function` with `group by` and `average` aggregate function as following:

```
WITH DATAA AS
(
SELECT 3 c1,5 c2,4 c3,3 c4 ,1 c5 FROM DUAL
UNION
-- case with same value at min for two columns
SELECT 1 c1,5 c2,4 c3,3 c4 ,1 c5 FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT  1 c1,3 c2,6 c3,9 c4 ,7 c5 FROM DUAL)

-- your query starts from here
select rn, avg(val) from
(select rn, val, 
      max(val) over (partition by rn) maxval,
      min(val) over (partition by rn) minval
from
(SELECT rownum rn, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
FROM DATAA)
unpivot
(val for vals in (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)))
where val not in (maxval, minval)
group by rn
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e89c7756dd1c2f72fbed8c3057c30d3) demo.

Cheers!!